# Using Apps on non-iOS devices?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipod-touch, simulator

Is there anyway to keep using the apps that I bought, if I no longer have an iOS device?

I am wondering if there is some sort iOS simulator on the PC.

Comment: related: http://superuser.com/questions/153454/can-i-run-ios-apps-on-my-mac

Answer (score 5):

If you are registered as a dev, you can get the iOS dev center that will let you emulate an iOS device..

http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action

as far as an app for a general user to download, i dont think there are any legal apps that let you do that.

Comment: Can I emulate the IOS apps even if I do not have the source code?  All I have right now are the binary apps stored in my iTunes folder.

Comment: @Mike No. There is no official way to emulate iOS apps without source code, for obvious reasons. If it were possible, it would certainly have to come from an illicit source, if not illegal.

Answer (score 2):

If you are registered as an iOS developer, and you have a mac, download xcode.

Make a copy of the `.ipa` file, right-click and open with Archive Utility.app (green icon)

Open the un-archived folder, and under "Payloads", you should find a `.app` file.

In Xcode, create a blank application under iOS. It will be created with no Targets, no build settings or anything.

Add the aforementioned `.app` file to your new project, set your build settings and "Build and Run" or "Run" in Xcode. As long as you have set the target as "iPhone Simulator", it should open in the iPhone/iPad Simulator, and you will be able to use the app.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. I don't even think you can use the development simulator to run them on a Mac. Would be far too easily pirate-able if you could just run them willy-nilly anywhere.