# Running iOS app on Windows NT4

Tags: windows, ios, emulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Apps on non-IOS devices?](https://superuser.com/questions/246649/using-apps-on-non-ios-devices)

Are there any emulators or such thing to run an iOS app on windows?

Anything like that available NT4?

(I don't make up the requirements, I just analyze them.)

**EDIT**

NT4 is a very hard requirement.  This is a common restriction for on-board avionics software.  It's not in my power to overhaul a whole industry.

Comment: NT4???  If this is for work, find a new job.  Immediately!!!  Anyplace still running NT4 is no place you want to be working.

Comment: @BBlake, ordinarily I'd agree with you, but this is a pretty special case... NT4 turns out to be a VERY common OS for on-board avionics software.  And, fortunately, I don't have to develop it.

Comment: @Robert Gowland - still, I support a developer who does similar stuff (marine GPS software - but they recently upgraded to Windows 2000!), however... you can still develop and everything on modern systems, using windows NT under emulation for testing and a real system just for deployment/last minute testing... I can't understand why anyone would use NT4 in a development cycle where you don't have to!

Comment: Why would you want to install any software (let alone a phone app) on to "on-board avionics" hardware?  Are you trying to crash a plane by playing Angry Birds??? :)

Comment: @techie007 Maybe they want to play Flight Control. :)

Comment: So there are planes up there running NT4??? That is scary... :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

iOS itself is not available for development on Windows even. It is restricted to OS X and requires a licensing fee per year.

That being said, there are no fully functioning and updated Emulators available currently. The best way to use iOS would be to purchase a device running it, or use the iOS Simulator that is part of the developers package, for OS X only.

Also NT4 is VERY old. I think you may want to consider upgrading your computer hardware and operating system soon.

Comment: It *officially* requires licenses and such, that doesn’t mean it can’t/won’t be reverse-engineered. I doubt that people who wrote emulators for game consoles bought licenses or signed NDAs. +1 for your answer, specifically for the operative term: **currently**.

Comment: I do fully expect it to be reverse engineered over time.

Comment: IOS apps can be run in the XCode device emulator without having an IOS developer account.

Answer (score 5):

***No.***

It just isn't possible.

Comment: Why not? I doubt that to be the case. In fact, the more popular it gets, the more drive there is to make an emulator. In fact, I’m fairly certain that I’ve already seen mentions of emulators in development environments and such (how/where do you think people write programs for them?)

Comment: @Synetechinc.: People write programs for them on ***Mac OS X***.

Comment: There is an "emulator" per se. The iOS Simulator. But it only runs on Mac.

Comment: I think my answer may provide a little more information to you @Syntechinc

Comment: Well there you have it, there is an emulator, albeit on the wrong system. That said, so what? I definitely remember there being emulators for all kinds of other systems (eg HP iPAQ, etc.) as part of VS2003 and such. There’s emulators for most game consoles. There is **no** reason that there cannot be an iOS emulator made.

Comment: @Synetechinc.: Yes, there is. It's that Apple has it locked down. And if someone actually made an iOS emulator for Windows, I'll bet Apple would be quick to crush it. What's the point of an emulator if you can't make apps for it? (There's no way to develop for iOS on Windows). And if you can't install apps on it? (You can't even install apps in the iOS Simulator).

Comment: And what, Atari, Nintendo, Sega, Microsoft, and Sony just stood around and purposely let people write emulators for their hardware? Locked-down means nothing to reverse-engineers, it just gives them a more fulfilling challenge.

Comment: @Synetechinc.: Well, then why hasn't anyone made one if iOS has been out for what, four years now?

Comment: Why did it take so long for a decent N64 emulator? Patience is a virtue. Besides, there isn’t as much demand for one as you would think since most people who care about it already have the phone.

Answer (score 4):

There are no iOS emulators for Windows. There is the iOS Simulator, but that only runs on Mac.