# Installing IOS on Dell A860

Tags: installation, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running iOS app on Windows NT4](https://superuser.com/questions/289094/running-ios-app-on-windows-nt4)

I want to install IOS on my Dell A860 laptop. Is it possible to install IOS on dell laptop?

Comment: iOS? As in **iOS** for iPhone, iPod, iPad?

Comment: I think you are trying to unite a computer and an OS that simply don't want to be united.

Comment: May I ask what you think the result would give you if it worked?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running iOS app on Windows NT4](http://superuser.com/questions/289094/running-ios-app-on-windows-nt4) and/or [Can I run iOS apps on my Mac?](http://superuser.com/questions/153454/can-i-run-ios-apps-on-my-mac) and/or [Using Apps on non-IOS devices?](http://superuser.com/questions/246649/using-apps-on-non-ios-devices)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*It is possible?* We went to the moon. Hell yes, this too is possible.

*Is it feasible?* HA HA HA HA! No.

If you want to explore OSX/Darwin (which essentially is iOS, under the hood) then I suggest you learn about OSX86. By the way, many believe that OSX86 is illegal, I don't believe it actually is. I think all it does is violate Apple's EULA, which means they owe you zero support and are totally not responsible for what happens... Of course, I'm suggesting you consider this from the perspective of someone who's purchased an OSX license ($30) for this. You're also in good shape if you have an Apple Developer account, or so I've been told by people who would know.

But back to the answer, **yes it CAN be done**. **No it's not going to happen** without profound development resources/knowledge.

Also, I'm not a lawyer.

Comment: And without the source code for IOS too, or years spent re-engineering OSX86 to do the same job.

Comment: Well, in terms of running OSX86 on a x86 machine, that's not a big job at all. I don't know how the UI architecture is different between iOS and OSX, but they're both the same fundamental OS (darwin/mach). I bet the right engineer from Apple could rig that up to work fairly quickly. But without knowing the key distinctions it could be nearly impossible to actually get "iOS" going on there. Still, there's a lot of great apple software mods out there. And insanely smart people doing remarkable things with it all, so never say never, I suppose.